# R merge bringing NAs from a

Tags: r, merge

I've seen this question asked before but the answers haven't fixed my problem, so I'm asking it again. Thanks for your help.

I have 2 dataframes, let's call them df1 and df2. Here's a printout of str:

```
> str(df1)
    'data.frame':   1380 obs. of  242 variables:
     $ ID       : num  1e+07 1e+07 1e+07 1e+07 1e+07 ...
     $ SNP1     : Factor w/ 3 levels "0","1","2": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
     $ SNP2     : Factor w/ 3 levels "0","1","2": 2 2 1 1 2 2 3 3 2 2 ...

> str(df2)
    'data.frame':   14124 obs. of  5 variables:
     $ ID       : num  10050840 10043900 10052815 10051221 10051589 ...
     $ SEX      : Factor w/ 4 levels "Female","Male",..: 2 3 1 1 3 1 2 3 3 3 ...
     $ RACE     : Factor w/ 11 levels "American Indian or Alaska Native",..: 3 9 9 9 3 9 9 9 9 9 ...
     $ ETHNIC   : Factor w/ 4 levels "DECLINED","HISPANIC",..: 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
     $ dDX      : Factor w/ 2 levels "SZ","HC": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

When I try to merge them...

```
>   df3 <- merge(df1,df2,by='ID',all=T)
```

...I get the following error, which (from what I've read) indicates that merge can't find ID in one of the datasets.

> Error in `[.data.frame`(x, rep.int(NA_integer_, nyy), nm.x, drop =
> FALSE) :    undefined columns selected

I have confirmed that all observations contain ID and that the spelling is correct. I'm wondering if it has something to do with the formatting of df1$ID (exponents, for some reason)? When I look at the data, df1$ID looks just like df2$ID (and the IDs overlap).  `options(scipen=999)` changes the exponents to standard notation, but doesn't change the error after merge. However, when I create a (very) truncated version of the data manually...

```
> ID <- c(10050840,10043900,10052815,10051221,10051589)
> SNP1 <- c(1,1,1,1,1)
> SNP2 <- c(2,2,1,1,2)
> SEX <- c(2,1,1,2,1)
> RACE <- c(9,7,8,6,1)
> ETHNIC <- c(3,3,1,2,1)
> dDX <- c(1,2,1,2,1)
> df1 <- data.frame(ID,SNP1,SNP2)
> df2 <- data.frame(ID,SEX,RACE,ETHNIC,dDX)
> df1$SNP1 <- as.factor(df1$SNP1)
> df1$SNP2 <- as.factor(df1$SNP2)
> df2$SEX <- as.factor(df2$SEX)
> df2$RACE <- as.factor(df2$RACE)
> df2$ETHNIC <- as.factor(df2$ETHNIC)
> df2$dDX <- as.factor(df2$dDX)
```

...the merge works perfectly.

Any other suggestions for things I should be trying or ways to identify the problem?

Comment: It would be easier to give a definitive answer if you run `dput(df1)` and `dput(df2)` and add the results to your question instead of the `str()` results. However, based on what you have posted, you could try changing the "ID" columns of both dfs to `as.integer()` e.g. `df1$ID <- as.integer(df1$ID)`. Also, to avoid numbers displaying with scientific notation e.g. "1e+07" you can use `options(scipen = 999)`. That way you'll be able to see if the values in each ID column in the same format.

Comment: When you use `names(df1)`, do you see `"ID"`, or `ID` with trailing spaces?

Comment: @LeroyTyrone - thanks. I used 'options(scipen=999)' as you mentioned and it didn't change the error after 'merge'. I used 'as.integer' and was able to change 'df1$ID' to integer it also didn't change the outcome of the merge.

Comment: @Werner - when I use 'names(df1)', I see '"ID"' without any trailing spaces. Same for 'names(df2)'.

Comment: Another thought is that df1$ID came from a factor vector that I turned into character and split using 'data.frame(do.call(rbind,strsplit(df$var,"_",fixed=TRUE)))' - the reason I did it this way was because the factor vector was listing the IDs as levels 1, 2, 3, etc. Is it possible that even though the ID vector APPEARS to include the IDs (not the factor levels), that it in fact carried the factor levels over?